# JQuery click from multiple anchor for ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple anchor tag generated by php from database like this

```
<a href="#" id="reply_doc" data-doc_value="1"></a>
<a href="#" id="reply_doc" data-doc_value="2"></a>
<a href="#" id="reply_doc" data-doc_value="3"></a>
```

Now I got JQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#reply_doc").click(function () {
    var a = $(this).data("doc_value");
    if (a != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_check/",
            data: "doc_reply=" + a,
            success: function (b) {
                alert(a+' ok. '+b)
            }
        });
    }
 });
});
```

This is only applying for the first anchor tag.
How can I do this for each anchor tag when that particular is clicked only that anchor will be affected and that particular value will be send with ajax.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: ID's are unique, use a class instead.

Comment: How on earth can you give same ID to three elements ?? ID means 'unique identification' . Please use class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` attribute is an **identifier**. As the name might suggest, that means it has to be **unique** so that it can identify a single element. In order to recognise multiple elements, you'll need to use a class instead:

```
<a href="#" class="reply_doc" data-doc_value="1"></a>
<a href="#" class="reply_doc" data-doc_value="2"></a>
<a href="#" class="reply_doc" data-doc_value="3"></a>

$(".reply_doc").click(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `id` to a `class`, and change your selector to `".reply_doc"`.

Your html is currently invalid because the `id` attribute should be unique. Although the browser doesn't jump up and down complaining when you break this rule, when you try to select an element by `id` it only finds the first (or, in some browsers, the last).

If, hypothetically, you have no control over the html structure you could instead select all anchor elements with the `data-doc_value` attribute:

```
$("a[data-doc_value]")...
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements cannot have same id so bind event on same class .

```
a href="#" class="option" id="reply_doc" data-doc_value="1"></a>
<a href="#" class="option" id="reply_doc" data-doc_value="2"></a>
<a href="#" id="reply_doc" class="option" data-doc_value="3"></a>
```

JQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".option").click(function () {
    var a = $(this).data("doc_value");
    if (a != "") {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_check/",
        data: "doc_reply=" + a,
        success: function (b) {
            alert(a+' ok. '+b)
        }
    });
}
});
});
```

Comment: thats a big mistake. I should remember it form now. its working fine with class. thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited again**   **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/SupzC/11/)**

```
<a href="#" class="reply_doc" data-doc_value="1">111</a><br>
<a href="#" class="reply_doc" data-doc_value="2">222</a><br>
<a href="#" class="reply_doc" data-doc_value="3">333</a><br>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".reply_doc").click(function () {
    var a = $("a.reply_doc").attr("data-doc_value"); //<-- Add this
    if (a != "") {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_check/",
        data: "doc_reply=" + a,
        success: function (b) {
            alert(a+' ok. '+b)
        }
    });
  }
 });
});
```

This way each time "**a**" will have unique value contained in **data-doc_value** on click

Comment: Did you test this? (Hint: the click handler will only be called for clicks on the first anchor with that id.)